# FB.getLoginStatus never firing callback in mobile browsers

Tags: android, facebook, ipad, mobile

I'm using `FB.getLoginStatus` (as per the documentation) and it works exactly as expected in all desktop browsers, but for reasons that I can't deduce, the call just simply vanishes into la-la land when it's called from iPad or Android (tested on a wide range of devices and OS versions).

I'm at a loss as to how to debug this. No exceptions are raised (that I can stick an alert into), so, I'm just totally stumped.  All suggestions on how to figure out what the issue might be, or better yet, a SOLUTION! would immensely appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this yet? I am having exact same problem. But in my case I am able to call it from everywhere except android's default browser (Samsung Galaxy S3).

Comment: unfortunately I have not.

Comment: Thanks. After a bit of research I found this bug listed on FB site: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/567636106594783 it claims that its fixed but not released yet.

Answer (score 2):

Most common problem is that the mobile site URL is not added in the app settings, check https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOURAPPID/summary/ and scroll down to the Mobile Web section.

Also: If you develop locally, pls keep in mind that eg 192.168.0.123 != localhost, which is a classic that cost me nearly an hour recently (all URLs/IPs have to be in the settings on facebook.com, otherwise the FB.getLoginStatus or any other auth event will not fire!)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the EXACT same issue and then realized that I was testing my mobile versions with domainname.com instead of www.domainname.com. Facebook will only redirect information to one or the other and not both.

Comment: unfortunately I'm testing my versions with the same subdomain across all scenarios, but +1 for good thought.